# Center of Mass Problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, density-function

Let $E=[0,3] \times  [-2,2] \times  [0,2]$ in Rectangular Coordinates with $0\le x \le 3, -2 \le y \le 2, 0 \le z \le 2$. Now let the density at each point E be equal to the distance from the z-axis. This means $(x,y,z)$ will be the center of mass E.

Now how can I find the two coordinates for the center of mass via symmetry and the third with an integral?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Not much since I cant figure out what it even is. I can graph a point for the upper and lower bound but that is about it since I have no idea what the shape is or how to find it.

Comment: What does your sentence "this means $(x,y,z)$ will be the center of mass $E$" even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance of any point from $z-$axis is given by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so density $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Note that the density $\rho$ is not a function of $z$ and hence the  $z$ coordinate of center of mass will simply be $z = 1$.

You can also use the symmetry about $x-$axis to conclude that the $y$ coordinate of the center of mass will be $0$.

So you are left with finding $x$ coordinate for the center of mass. For that, consider mass of unit height (unit $z$) in $XY$ plane above $x-$axis (as there is symmetry above and below $x-$axis).

Mass $m = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2} \int_0^3  \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ dx \ dy$

And, $\overline{x} = \displaystyle \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{2} \int_0^3 x \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ dx \ dy$

---

Just as a side note, the second integral can be evaluated over $dx$ using $u = y^2+x^2$ substitution. Then hyperbolic substitution works over $dy$.

To make it easier to evaluate the first integral - if you are familiar with line integral of vector fields and Green's theorem, please note line integral of the vector field $\frac{1}{3}(-y \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, x \sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ over the closed curve which is perimeter of the rectangle with vertices $A(0,0), B(3, 0), C(3,2), D(0,2)$, is same as the first integral to find mass. Line integral over $AB$ and $DA$ is zero. So after parametrization, this translates to line integral over $BC$ and $CD$ as below.

$\displaystyle \int_0^2 \sqrt{t^2+9} \ dt + \frac{2}{3}\int_0^3 \sqrt{t^2+4} \ dt$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this figure will help... the contours show equal density:

[image]

Comment: What are all of those shells? I understand your coordinate system but I am now following how I am suppose to find 2 coordinates of the center of mass and the third via an integral.

Comment: Your picture does help me visualize it so thank you but how would I use that to find the 3 sets of coordinates?

Comment: Ooops... see fixed contour plot.

Comment: It seems like there are more than just 2 points which points is this question referring to? I am also a bit confused why there are so many shells. From this picture all I can really see is the total width, height and  depth but that is already stated in the question. I cant really tell the coordinates of each of these specific shells.

Comment: Each shell is at a different (constant) density.

Comment: how did you determine where to place each shell?

Comment: I am still so confused I still dont know what I am even suppose to do. What are these points that I am looking for?

Comment: You mainly need to find $x$ coordinate. Rest do not require integral. Writing the integral is not that difficult. But it is not a straightforward integral to evaluate the mass, both in cartesian and polar coordinates.